# I can't connect to SQL Server from VB.NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I can't connect to SQL Server using vb.net.

Here is my code:

```
Imports system.data.sqlclient

PUBLIC CLASS customer_typer

    Dim connectionstring as string = "data source = wisdon; initial catalog = stock_management; user id = sa; password = managerz "

    Dim mycommand as new sqlcommand
    Dim myconnection = new sqlcomma d (connectionstring)

    PRIVATE SUB CUSTOMER_BT
        dim sqlstr as string
        Sqlstr = " insert into customer_type(customer_type) values"  & _
            "(' " & customertyper_txt.text & " ')"
        Mycommand = new sqlclient.sqlcommand (sqlstr, myconnection)

        Mycommand.executeNonQuery ()

        Myconnection.close
```

`Customer_type` is the button I am writing the code

`Customertype_txt` is the textbox

Comment: What specifically does *I cant connect* mean? What's stopping you from connecting? Do you get an error message? If so, what is that message? You've given us no details that we can use, and we have no access to your database to test using what you've posted. It's your job to clearly describe the problem and provide the details, and ours to try to solve your problem. Please [edit] your post to do your part of the work, so that we can do ours.

Comment: There is at least one typo. `Dim my connection = new sqlcomma d(connectionstring)` Also, you should probably check to see if the `new sqlcommand(connectionstring)`, which is what you mean to say, is actually successful before attempting to run a query.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to open your connection. Also you tried to declare your connection as a command. I have added parameters to protect against sql injection as suggested by @marc_s.
The Using...End Using statements ensure that your objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

```
Using myconnection = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
            Dim Sqlstr As String = " insert into customer_type(customer_type) values(@CustomerType);"
            Using mycommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(Sqlstr, myconnection)
                mycommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = customertyper_txt.text
                myconnection.Open()
                mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myconnection.Close()
            End Using
End Using
```